# Option selected for dynamic divs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In edit case I am genrating 4 HTML div via for loop :

```
@for($i=0;$i < 4;$i++)
    <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="eng_country[]" id="eng_country" class="form-control profile-engform new-font addlisting_classic" placeholder="Country">
                <option value=""> Country </option>
                @foreach($result['total_exp_country'] as $key=>$value)
                    <option>{{$value->country_eng}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        <span class="text-danger text_error" id="eng_country_error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Inside this, I am populating the list of the country an option.

I am getting selected country list in that variable result like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#354 ▼
    +"id": "1"
    +"worker_id": "42"
    +"country_id": "1"
    +"exp_year": "2"
    +"added_date": "2018-01-30 00:00:00"
    +"country_eng": "India"
    +"country_arb": "الهند"
    +"ordering": "2"
  }
  1 => {#355 ▼
    +"id": "2"
    +"worker_id": "42"
    +"country_id": "2"
    +"exp_year": "1"
    +"added_date": "2018-01-31 00:00:00"
    +"country_eng": "Srilanka"
    +"country_arb": "سيريلانكا"
    +"ordering": "1"
  }
]
```

My problem is that I want to select the option value whatever I am getting from this variable if it come blank no value should be selected

```
values:




After  <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($result['total_exp_country']);exit;  ?>

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [country_eng] => India
            [country_arb] => Ø§Ù„Ù‡Ù†Ø¯
            [ordering] => 2
            [added_date] => 2018-01-30 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [country_eng] => Srilanka
            [country_arb] => Ø³ÙŠØ±ÙŠÙ„Ø§Ù†ÙƒØ§
            [ordering] => 1
            [added_date] => 2018-01-31 00:00:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [country_eng] => UAE
            [country_arb] => Ø§Ù„Ø£Ù…Ø§Ø±Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù…ØªØ­Ø¯Ø©
            [ordering] => 2
            [added_date] => 2018-01-29 00:00:00
        )

)



And array data for : $result['exp_country']


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [worker_id] => 42
            [country_id] => 1
            [exp_year] => 2
            [added_date] => 2018-01-30 00:00:00
            [country_eng] => India
            [country_arb] => Ø§Ù„Ù‡Ù†Ø¯
            [ordering] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [worker_id] => 42
            [country_id] => 2
            [exp_year] => 1
            [added_date] => 2018-01-31 00:00:00
            [country_eng] => Srilanka
            [country_arb] => Ø³ÙŠØ±ÙŠÙ„Ø§Ù†ÙƒØ§
            [ordering] => 1
        )

)



I want to match id with country id for selected option ...
```

Comment: add a if condition if the country_id == to the select options country_id

Comment: can u please update my question ??

Comment: I did this  {{($result['exp_country'][$key]==$value->id) ? "selected" : ""}} but its not working..

Comment: you want multiple select is it ?

Comment: try this {{($result['exp_country'][$key][id]==$value->id) ? "selected" : ""}}
or
{{($result['exp_country'][$key]->id==$value->id) ? "selected" : ""}}

Comment: Not working i already done this but its not working ..

Comment: can u add $result['exp_country'] data and $result['total_exp_country'] data to the question and update it

Comment: instead of id u should try country_id i guess

Comment: What are the variables that are being passed to this view? Could you specify the resource variable, if any?

Comment: try this {{($result['exp_country'][$key]['country_id']==$value->country_id) ? "selected" : ""}} or {{($result['exp_country'][$key]->country_id==$value->country_id) ? "selected" : ""}}

Comment: not working @ Jigs1212

Comment: @linktoahref see my updation in question

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
@foreach($result['total_exp_country'] as $key=>$value)
    <option 
        @if($result['exp_country'][$key]['country_id']==$value->country_id) 
            selected 
        @endif 
        value="{{$value->country_id}}">{{$value->country_eng}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: not working giving error like :   1/1
                            FatalErrorException in 72f4cbcdee898721adff5db27588426de8ad956d.php line 371:
                            Cannot use object of type stdClass as array